# Beam PAssert messes up the Row

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am exploring testing with Beam and encountered a weird problem.

My driver program works as expected, but its test is failing with an error like this:

```
Expected: iterable with items [<Row: 
project_id:count
count_in:2
count_out:0
type:null
window_max_ts:86399999
>] in any order
     but: not matched: <Row: 
project_id:p1
count_in:2
count_out:0
type:count
window_max_ts:86399999
>
```

And here is my PAssert code:

```
PAssert
            .that(output)
            .inWindow(window)
            .containsInAnyOrder(
                Row
                    .withSchema(OUTPUT_SCHEMA)
                    .withFieldValue("type", "count")
                    .withFieldValue("count_in", 2L)
                    .withFieldValue("count_out", 0L)
                    .withFieldValue(AddWindowTimestamp.TIMESTAMP_FIELD, window.maxTimestamp().getMillis())
                    .build()
            );
```

On the last step of my pipeline, I log the element in question.

```
[direct-runner-worker] DEBUG co.botanalytics.data.processing.beam.transforms.Log - Window: [maxTimestamp=1970-01-01T23:59:59.999Z], Pane: [PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}], Element: Row: 
project_id:p1
count_in:2
count_out:0
type:count
window_max_ts:86399999
```

This is the expected result.

When I debugged the test, the problem boiled down to `CoderUtils` from Beam Java SDK.

After `CoderUtils` encodes and decodes, it produces a completely different expected Row. All of its fields are messed up, and as a result, PAssert fails.

I am wondering if there are any solutions to this problem. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

`OUTPUT_SCHEMA` definition:

```
private static final transient Schema SCHEMA = Schema
            .builder()
            .addStringField("project_id")
            .addNullableField("type", Schema.FieldType.STRING)
            .addInt64Field("count_in")
            .addInt64Field("count_out")
            .build();
```

Comment: Seams the problem is not in the output tested but in how you define the test fields. Could you please provide more details of how do you define the `output` and your `OUTPUT_SCHEMA` ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva I added the schema definition. If that's the case, shouldn't it be failing when run normally as well? It fails when using PAssert.

Comment: The code can work as expected and the test fails. I believe that is happening because of a misconfiguration on the PAssert. Please test the following: `1-` add the project tag in the test row definition : `.withFieldValue("project_id", "p1")` and test it, It may solve the problem of the crossed parameters. `2-` the error `Expected: iterable with items` can be solved if you change `.that(output)` for `.that(output.toArray())`. It`s expecting an array but just receiving a single `Row`. Please inform me if you got success, so then I can post an answer. I hope it helps! :)

Comment: @ewertonvsilva I thought I tried this but somehow I missed it. Thanks for pointing out! PCollection does not have a `toArray` method so instead I provided results to `containsInAnyOrder` inside a Row array.

Comment: Great, so I understand that its working, right ? I will post an official answer with the details and pointing to the correct function to insert the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can work as expected and the test fails. I believe that is happening because of an error on the PAssert definition.

- Add the project tag in the test row definition `.withFieldValue("project_id", "p1")`, it may solve the problem of the crossed parameters.
- For the error `Expected: iterable with items [<Row: ... >] in any order but: not matched:` please provide the `output` variable as an `Array of Rows`, instead of only a single `Row`. Its expecting an `array` but just receiving a single `Row`.

Your final code will be something like this:

```
// just an example to convert to array, choose any suitable way for you
    Foo[] array = new Foo[output.size()];
    output.toArray(array);

        PAssert
                    .that(output)
                    .inWindow(window)
                    .containsInAnyOrder(
                        Row
                            .withSchema(OUTPUT_SCHEMA)
                            .withFieldValue("project_id", "p1")
                            .withFieldValue("type", "count")
                            .withFieldValue("count_in", 2L)
                            .withFieldValue("count_out", 0L)
                            .withFieldValue(AddWindowTimestamp.TIMESTAMP_FIELD, window.maxTimestamp().getMillis())
                            .build()
                    );
```

Comment: For me, wrapping the Row passed to the `containsInAnyOrder` inside an array actually produced the correct result. But nevertheless, you pointed me in the right direction and it worked out. I am accepting this answer.

Comment: I appreciate. You can edit my answer with any suggested improvement if you like.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to anyone who might bump into this :)